# Image browser for raw Canon cr2 files

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, preview, canon

I would like to have quick preview of raw cr2 files on my mac. When I was Windows user I've used Irfan View. On a mac I've tried preview but it chokes multiple (200+) high-resolution cr2 files.

Can you recommend a program that would enable me to make quick selection of photos (eg. 4 photos out of 200). What would be smooth during browsing such large sets of large images?

Comment: If you're already working in raw, have you considered getting photoshop and/or Lightroom? I love the Adobe Camera Raw interface.

Comment: Idk what it's like with Canon raw, but Adobe makes a total mess of Nikon raw; completely ignores any existing processing & starts from scratch. I'd see if Canon make their own app, Nikon do & it's a world better than LR or PS for getting a) a quick overview & b) preserving intended 'look', then tif to PS for any additional work. You can still use Adobe raw at this stage, but from a better start point.